# How to use group by in sql? (I need sequelize)

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have

```
SELECT [id], [company_number], [country_code] 
FROM [core].[company] 
WHERE [core].[company].[id] IN (N'DK-10001560') 
GROUP BY [country_code]
```

But it fails with this error:

```
Column 'core.company.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Works fine without `GROUP BY`

Comment: Are you trying to get a unique `country_code`?  could you explain what your query is trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GROUP BY statement groups rows that have the same values into summary rows, in your case, it is the country_code.

It is often used with aggregate functions (COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), AVG()) to group the result-set by one or more columns.

That means, for expl : you want to count how many company_number per country_code

So, what you can do is :

```
    SELECT id, company_number, count(country_code )
    FROM core.company 
    WHERE core.company.id IN (N'DK-10001560') 
    GROUP BY id, company_number
```

Hope this helps ;)